# Prevent refresh when using dynamic content

Tags: javascript, dynamic-content

I've used basic JS to change content on a website without traditional hyperlinks. I use it to load content in another file and insert it into a HTML `<div>`. Each content page is wrapped inside a `<div>`.

```
<!-- Inside head -->
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $("#content").load("home.html");
        $("#home").click(function(){
            $("#content").load("home.html")
        });
        $("#page1").click(function(){
            $("#content").load("page1.html")
        });
        $("#page2").click(function(){
            $("#content").load("page2.html")
        });
    });
</script>

<!-- Inside body -->
<div id="content">
    <!-- Dynamic content here -->
</div>
```

Recently I noticed that this doesn't strictly work as I intended. Yes, it uses the same page to insert content, but it also refreshes the page, which is a bit annoying when the link is not at the top of the page. So one has to scroll back down to see the loaded content.

How could I go about achieving truly dynamic content? Is an entirely new construct needed?

Comment: If your trigger for the click is an `a` tag, `return false` or add the `event` as an argument to the click handler and `preventDefault()`

Comment: @click2install As in `return false` from the JS function, e.g. the innermost functions above?

Comment: `$("#home").click(function(){  $("#content").load("home.html"); return false;});`

Comment: or, `$("#home").click(function(e){ $("#content").load("home.html"); e.preventDefault();});`

Comment: This entire solution seems like you are reinventing the wheel. Why not just load all the content statically from the start and just hide it all. Then, use the clicks to show the desired section?

Comment: @ScottMarcus I'm not HTML savvy at all.. So I'm not aware of such methods. But I'll have to investigate!

Comment: @click2install Thanks a lot! Works like a charm. And a simple fix. Perfect.

Comment: @ScottMarcus dont disagree with first part, although this could be a lightweight content loader (even moreso without jq) but if there are numerous click triggers, that could be a lot of HTML being dumped into the DOM, when one may not ever visit some of the targets being loaded

Comment: @click2install Fair point. But, since all I'm seeing loaded in the post is client-side code, I'm inclined to think that there's not a lot of truly dynamic content here.

Comment: @ScottMarcus fair call

Comment: @ScottMarcus Could I ask for a pointer, a name or something to start looking for the method you described?

Comment: @Felix I updated my answer with an example

Comment: @Felix All that's involved is the creation of a CSS class that can be applied to the container elements by default and then upon the clicking of one of your links the appropriate element has that class removed from it so that it is now shown. **[Here's the idea.](https://jsfiddle.net/t0jueL3m/39/)**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can prevent an `a` tag from reloading the page by either returning false or preventing the event handler from doing its default action, like:

```
$("#home").click(function()
{ 
   $("#content").load("home.html"); 
   return false;
});
```

or

```
$("#home").click(function(e)
{ 
   $("#content").load("home.html"); 
   e.preventDefault();
});
```

also, just for brevity, your `ready` handler can be shortened to:

```
// no need for $(document).ready(function(), can just be as below 
$(function() 
{
   // other stuff here after document is ready
});
```

As @ScottMarcus suggested you could just load your content and hide it by default, then in the click handlers show your content based on what was clicked:

```
<a href="#" id="home">Home</a>
<div id="content">
  <div id="home-content">Home content here, hide it on page load with css</div>
  <div id="page1-content">Page 1 content here, hide it on page load with css</div>
  <div id="page2-content">Page 2content here, hide it on page load with css</div>
</div>

#content > div
{
  display: none;
}    

// if you dont want to hide home on page load
#home-content
{
  display: block;
}

$("#home").click(function()
{ 
   $('#content > div').hide(); // could also use .fadeOut()
   $("#home-content").show(); // could also use .fadeIn()
   return false;
});
```

Comment: `fadeIn` `fadeOut` will be clunky if you have lots of HTML, you are better to use CSS for transitions than JavaScript - if you Google CSS transitions you will find some good resources. If your HTML is minimal then JavaScript is "probably" ok

Comment: Similarly, instead of `hide` `show` you could use `.addClass('hidden')`, `.removeClass('hidden')` and in CSS add a `.hidden { display: none; }` - lots of choices

Comment: It's a good solution that is based on OPs original idea. I just always cringe a little when hyperlinks are used as JavaScript tirggers and thus, cancelling of the native behavior becomes a requirement. In situations like that, I always opt to use a different element that won't require that, like a `span`. But, that's just my 2 cents. ;)

Comment: @ScottMarcus a `button` is my goto for this sort of thing, CSS is our friend to make things look however we want.

Comment: But, remember that HTML is for semantics and semantics affect the usability of your UI.